# In Spark's Java API, how can I select columns from a Dataset<Row> using regular expressions?

Tags: java, apache-spark

**Link to accepted answer** - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56447083/8543652

Using Spark's Java API, I want to select a subset of columns from an existing Dataset using a regular expression and house them in a new Dataset.

For example, suppose I have a Dataset with a large number of Columns:

```
String[] columnNames = exampleDF.columns();
```

where

```
columnNames = {foo1,foo2,...,foon,bar1,bar2,...,bark}
```

Suppose from the above I wish to create a new Dataset from exampleDF containing only the foo columns.

So far, I have tried creating a regular expression helper function using plain Java and then tried placing this into the Dataset's select method:

```
String[] filterColumns(Dataset<Row> inputDF, String regEx){

      // Get the column names, convert to a stream of strings
      Stream<String> columnStream = Arrays.stream(inputDF.columns());

      // Create a predicate from the desired regular expression
      Predicate<String> pred = Pattern.compile(regEx).asPredicate(); 

      // Filter the streamed string based on the predicate, then convert to an array
      return columnStream.filter(pred).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[0]);

Dataset<Row> outputDF = exampleDF.select(filterColumns(exampleDF, "foo."));
```

I understand that a varargs can accept an array as an input, and I was hoping the select function would accept said array. However rather strangely, it appears as though you must first enter a string, then a string vararg.

For example if instead my helper function output an array as:

```
String[] cumbersomeArray = {foo2,foo3,...,foon}
```

I could input:

```
Dataset<Row> outputDF = exampleDF.select("foo1",filterColumns(outputDF, cumbersomeArray))
```

and that would work.

However, that is not very satisfactory because then I would have to modify the helper function to output a strange version of the array, thereby defeating the purpose of a helper function.

I have also tried the selectExpr method, but it seems to only take in a SQL-like expression.

I am also aware of Dataset's colRegex method, but couldn't find any examples or documentation (In fact, this is why I decided to try and implement my own helper function).

My questions are thus as follows:

1) Is it possible to change my helper function to output a String followed by a String[] such that I can place it straight into the Dataset's select method?

2) Alternatively, would my current helper function work as-is inside some other method?

3) Would colRegex or some other method I am unaware of help me here? If so, can you provide an example and documentation?

I would prefer to stick to native Java/Spark objects rather than rely on any third party libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Dataset` `select` method you are using here is `select(String col, String... cols)` but you could use the `select(Column... cols)` method instead by returning an array of `Columns` from your helper function as opposed to an array of `String`.

change to:

```
return columnStream.filter(pred).map(x -> new Column(x)).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new Column[0])
```

then you can just use the returned array like:

```
Dataset<Row> outputDF = exampleDF.select(filterColumns(outputDF, cumbersomeArray))
```